# How to bind multiple path variables in Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a url like this: /category/1234#123456

I need to bind both ids in my request handler method so I created my controller as below:

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/category/{parentId}#{childId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
> public ModelAndView requestHandler(@PathVariable("parentId") Long parentId, @PathVariable("childId") Long childId){
> //some code
> }
> ```

but I am getting an error and I believe the #{childId} making that error. 
my question is how can I bind both variable when there is a # sign between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of the url after # is not sent to the server and hence you cannot get that as a path variable.

You can do one of the following:

1. Change the url to /category/1234/123456 and the request mapping to `@RequestMapping(value = "/category/{parentId}#{childId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`
2. Change the url to /category/1234?childId=123456 and change childId to `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`